# Docking a Dock Panel In Wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have been trying to dock a dock panel.But couldn't.Generally in windows forms if we dock a panel it will fit correctly. i searched in google which shows only for docking the buttons in dock panel.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="Azure">
            <TextBlock Width="600"></TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="Black"></DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="top" Background="Cornsilk"></DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements you're binding to the right and top are empty ...

So, you get the one you set the width to to the left (600), then the right one takes width = 0, and the last element fills the rest (since the default for `LastChildFill` is true), hence you see the Cornsilk color filling everything else.

Seems to work :)

You can also set the LastChildFill to false in the dockpanel like this:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
```

and then you won't even see the Cornsilk, since it's size is zero as well.